# How resize image with custom ratio using Intervention image manipulation library in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image-manipulation

I want to resize an image with custom ratio `(width:height)=(5:1)`

- Using [Intervention image manipulation library](http://image.intervention.io/) in `laravel`.
- It's not a problem if the image stretches. I don't want to put any fixed height or width.

so please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Then what is your problem/question, what difficulties you are facing ?

Comment: normally I can resize image maintaining the actual image ratio.But I want to resize the image using custom ratio such as 5:1 or 3:2...How to do this?

Comment: You may check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876660/intervention-image-exception-imagenotwritableexception-using-laravel-4/22876779#22876779), could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the solution,but I don't want to use any static height or width...

Comment: Them use only dynamic `width` and leave the height to be adjusted automatically, could be done I think.

Comment: If I use only width and leave the height to be adjusted automatically then I think it will maintain the ratio of actual image..but I want to use custom ratio and dynamic width or height....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think intervention image library has this option in their resize function. you can use `getimagesize()` php function to get the height and width and divide width with 5 (in your case its 5 because you want 5:1) to get the height.

```
$image=getimagesize($image_file);
$width=$image[0]; // $image[0] is the width
$height=$image[0]/5; // $image[1] is the height
```

Than you can just use your intervention's `resize()` function to resize to that height and width.

```
Image::make($source_image)
     ->resize($width,$height ,false,false)
     ->save($destination);`
```

Comment: though this will stretch the image. :(

Comment: Oh,How stupid I am.I didn't find this easy solution.Thanks bro...you saved my day....

Comment: or you can use the functions width() and height() in the intervention image object.

Answer (score 9):

I think the best solution might be, to use [fit()](http://image.intervention.io/api/fit) from the library.

Like this:

```
// open 4/3 image for example
$image = Image::make('foo.jpg');

// your desired ratio
$ratio = 16/9;

// resize
$image->fit($image->width(), intval($image->width() / $ratio));
```

It don't stretches the image.

Answer (score 2):

I choose fit() rather than resize() to modify the picture avoiding to stretch the image to much.

I use a php snippet in my project, which might be helpful.

```
$img = Image::make($pictureOriginalPath);
// Picture ratio
$ratio = 4/3;

// Check the current size of img is appropriate or not,
// if ratio of current img is greater than 1.33, then crop
if(intval($img->width()/$ratio > $img->height()))
{
    // Fit the img to ratio of 4:3, based on the height
    $img->fit(intval($img->height() * $ratio),$img->height());
} 
else
{
    // Fit the img to ratio of 4:3, based on the width
    $img->fit($img->width(), intval($img->width()/$ratio));
}

// Save, still need throw exception
$img->save($pictureNewPath);
```