# How to resize image before upload in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, image

I want to resize image beofre upload it into database. I store image in this way

```
  if ($image) {
     $image_name = hexdec(uniqid());
       $ext      = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
       $image_full_name = $image_name . '.' . $ext;
       $upload_path     = 'foods/';
       $upload_path1    = 'images/foods/';
       $image_url       = $upload_path . $image_full_name;
       $success         = $image->move($upload_path1, $image_full_name);

        }
```

Now, I want to resize image before uploading it. I try to use intervation package, I try this

```
if ($image) {
     $image_name = hexdec(uniqid());
       $ext      = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
       $image_full_name = $image_name . '.' . $ext;
       $upload_path     = 'foods/';
       $upload_path1    = 'images/foods/';
       $image_url       = $upload_path . $image_full_name;
       $img = Image::make($image)->resize(300, 200);
       $img->save($upload_path1, 60, $image_full_name);

        }
```

and I got this error

```
 "Encoding format (1691942233153059.jpg) is not supported."
```

What is the best way to resize image before upload and also set image with unique name?

Comment: It looks like an error with your usage of intervention image. 

There's a discussion about this error for that package at https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/231 

Does the suggestion from that thread of using $img->save('foo' . $img->getClientOriginalExtension()); work for you?

Comment: No, It's through this error ""Command (GetClientOriginalExtension) is not available for driver (Gd).""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- use `getRealPath()` inside `Image::make()`

2- save image in particular path.

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image       = $request->file('image');
    $file_name    = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());              
    $image_resize->resize(300, 100);
    $image_resize->save(public_path('img/' .$file_name));
}
```

Comment: I just use your code and I got this error " "Can't write image data to path ""

Comment: Please checkout this link you may find the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497694/cant-write-image-data-to-path-in-laravel-using-the-intervention-library