# Laravel - Can't write image data

Tags: laravel, image, storage

I'm trying to save a image, but I keep getting the same error:

Error: *Can't write image data to path (../storage/app/upload/620a64feaab05.png)*

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $img = Image::make(request('image'));

        $img->resize(140, null, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
        
        $path = 'upload/'. uniqid(). '.png';
        $img->save('../storage/app/'. $path, 20, 'png');
        $img = explode('/',$path);
        Person::updateImage($img[1]);
    }
```

I think this started to occour after I make the storage:link command and create the symbolic link.
Any clue please?

Comment: I don't think `../storage` is getting you to the correct path. Use the `storage_path` helper function instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't write image data to path in laravel using the Intervention library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497694/cant-write-image-data-to-path-in-laravel-using-the-intervention-library)