# Laravel 4 can not upload image

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel 4.2 on wamp server.

Error:

> Intervention \ Image \ Exception \ NotWritableException Can't write
>   image data to path (C:\wamp\www\laravel.....)

my script:

```
$image = Input::file('image');
$filename = date('Y-m-d-H:i:s').".".$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$path = public_path('img/products/' . $filename);
Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save($path);
```

Comment: try to do a search first. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876660/intervention-image-exception-imagenotwritableexception-using-laravel-4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876660/intervention-image-exception-imagenotwritableexception-using-laravel-4)

Comment: i following this question but get error.

Comment: You must put 777 permissions to `public/img/products/` folder

Answer (score 0):

You must enable FileInfo extension and PHP >= 5.3 (preferably 5.4) and GD or Imagick extensions for image manipulations